# C# Call method By button

Tags: c#, json, methods

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        request;
    }
```

This is the error I get:

```
Error CS0201 Entrance, Call, Increase, Decrease, and New Object Expression can only be used as statements.
```

How can I call the request method and fix this?

```
   private void request(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://crest-safe.azurewebsites.net/users/checkpayment/vouchers?token=mainBackup&apiKey=pds3583e");
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new User("cultureLand", pin));
            streamWriter.Write(json);
        }
    }
```

Comment: call it like `request(sender,e)`?

Comment: @Sajid It solve error but I will check that working! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not invoking the method in correct way.
Replace the following code for button1_Click() method:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    request(null,null);
}
```

You can send null values as "sender" and "e" arguments so the method will execute without problem.